# apply css style to a part of string change if it is quoted in razor asp.net

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

is it possible to style a subpart of a string? I want to apply the style only to the word in quotes.

**My cshtml**

```
        {
            <div class="h-44 overflow-auto text-left mx-4 mb-4">
                <p id="countError" class=" main-text-color mb-2 w-[70%] font-semibold">@Model.ToString().Replace("|", " ")</p>
                <p class="main-text-color">Os seguintes erros foram:</p>



                @foreach (var error in Model.Errors)
                {
                    var errors = error.Split(Environment.NewLine);
                    bool firsLine = true;

                    foreach (var item in errors)
                    {
                        
                        if (firsLine)
                        {
                            <p class="leading-8 text-red-500 font-spec-bold">
                              @Html.Raw(item)
                            </p>
                            firsLine = false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <p id="teste" class=" leading-8 main-text-color ">
                                @Html.Raw(item);
                            </p>
                        }

                    }
                }
            </div>
        }
```

Example of what I need:

The String comes like this:

*I need this "WORD" in bold.*

I need it to look like this:

*I need this **"WORD"** in bold.*

*Thanks!*

I didn't find a similar example here, but if there is something I would appreciate the guidance.

Comment: You can use `string.Replace` and replace your Word with your Word in a `span` element with a `className` that applies bold styling to the text.

Comment: @Ryan,  Thanks for the tip, but the word will be dynamic, it won't always be the same. That's why I wanted to take the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better put word into `{}` like this:
I need this {WORD} in bold.

So that you can replace `{` with `<b>`,`}` with `</b>`:

```
@Html.Raw(item.Replace("{", "<b>").Replace("}", "</b>"))
```

result:

[image]

Comment: thanks, It would be a solution, but I wouldn't want to mess with the back. I wanted to learn how to deal at the front only. Thank you for your attention in helping me.

Comment: If you want to replace `""` with `<b></b>`,  it will be difficult.Because it is hard to tell which `""`  is replace with`<b>` or `</b>`.